# check if an android app is malware before installation

Tags: android, google-play

I want to access the apk file of any app before installation.
In more details: in google play store when the user clicks on Install button I want my application to access the apk file of the application that the user wants to download, and analyze this apk file and be able to whether allow the installation or stop it.

is that possible and if so how to approach this

Comment: Hi. Did you ever figure out how to do this? I've been trying and reading some things and I can't get the app to receive any broadcast when I try to install an app through its APK...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android this functionality was introduced in Android 4.2. It is usually used by anti-malware products like [Google Play Protect](https://www.android.com/play-protect/) is known as a "Package Verifier". There is a [good blog post on it here](http://irq5.io/2014/12/01/android-internals-package-verifiers/).

The short answer is this has to be done as part of the phone manufacturing process as it is so critical to security. So the answer is it can be done, but if you write this code you will need to get a phone manufacturer to include your code as part of a phone system image.

Most third party anti-malware products instead rely on analyzing the APK after the install happens by listening to the [package added notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not possible in the way that you want. Android's OS is pretty well locked down. You might be able to do something if the device was rooted but at that point you may as well write your own OS fork. You can attempt to do someting with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast but you will not be able to analyze the apk freely nor will you be able to stop the installation of it.